# Source config field of form ui component

Tags: magento2

This is field form category_form.xml file:

```
    <field name="store_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

What does this line bellow mean:

```
<item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
```